# Add class files to existing project java netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, .class-file

I have a project with java files in it. My class files are in a jar and I want to add them to my project. This is how I've added the class files: libraries > add jar. But my html applet can't find the class files, the error I'm getting is noClassDefFoundError. How to solve this? (I have searched on internet for a solution but my problem is still there).

Answer (score 0):

You have to export classes to project. In eclipse you have to "tick" library, I assume NetBeans have the same option somewhere. If you don't export library, your program is trying to find it and can't do it because it is not a "global" library known to all programs.

Comment: Anyone who knows how to export a library in NetBeans?

Comment: you normally should find them in the /lib directory somewhere in your project, if not they are extern and you have to search them over the prefferences of your project in Netbeans

Comment: they are in my lib directory but my applet cant find the files